# Automated testing in cloud

Tags: automated-testing, continuous-integration, windows

I have a Windows application using OpenGL and automated E2E test environment based on [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) framework. Tests run locally and are not available outside of my company network. As we have two different development teams in different geographical locations without access to our network I would like to:

- have a dedicated machine (or rent such a PC) available via ssh or similar to deploy app and execute tests
- be able to query test progress / status
- get test results for usage in continuous integration system (Jenkins)

What are the possible solutions, what tools / systems do you use in your organizations ?

Comment: What do you mean by your 3rd requirements: "get test results in..."?

Comment: I would like to test every nightly build so I need a way to install my application, execute tests and get the result with failure report (if any). I am going to use this results in Continuous Integration system e.g. Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a free (or paid depending on your circumstances) [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) account?

Comment: This might be an option but I am not familiar with ec2 yet. Is there a possibility to use custom operating system image ?

Comment: Yes you can create a Virtual Machine image using VMWare and export that image to EC2.  http://serverfault.com/questions/223233/how-to-setting-up-amazon-ec2-with-own-os-and-db

Comment: This blogpost (although about Watir) gives some insight into using the EC2 platform for test automation with Jenkins: http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/29/running-your-watir-webdriver-tests-in-the-cloud-for-free/